# How to display count(*) to label text in asp.net using c#.net

Tags: asp.net

How to display count(*) to label text in asp.net using c#.net i mean  tbl1 is Having 10 rows that 10 value set to label text

`con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(newsid)from tbl_news where newsid=44,con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);

        con.Close();
        lbl_so.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count.ToString();`

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this one,

```
con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select count(newsid) as totalRow from tbl_news where newsid=44,con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);   
        con.Close();

        lbl_so.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["totalRow"].ToString();
```